# Fixing a parameter when using std::bind

Tags: c++11

This code doesn't compile, I don't get why:

```
struct C { int a;};

void foo(C c, int s)
{
  cout << c.a << s;
}

int main()
{
  std::function<void(C,int)> call = std::bind(&foo,std::placeholders::_1,5);
  C c;
  c.a = 5;
  call(c);
  return 0;
}
```

I get:

`No match for call to std::function<void(C,int)> (C&)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `bind()` expression `std::bind(&foo, _1, 5)` produces a unary function. You try to use a unary function to initialize a binary `std::function<void(c, int)>`. Did you mean to use something like this?

```
std::function<void(C)> call = std::bind(&foo, _1, 5);
```

Comment: Ah!!! Didn't know it worked like this. Oops, shame. Yes that's what I intended. Thank you